# SQL Oracle CREATE - unknown issue

Tags: sql, oracle

After copping much abuse for the first time I asked this question I have calmed down and I am trying again and trying to be more specific.

I have done an assignment for Uni and this was the following prompt for one of the questions:

```
Write Create Table SQL statements for the relational schema that you have created
Place the text in the specified location in the file: ASS1_SQL.TXT
• All tables must have primary keys.
• All tables must have appropriate foreign key constraints.
• Each foreign key column must have identical column name, datatype and size of the primary key
that it refers to
• Add any NOT NULL constraints as dictated by the ERD
• The following columns data types and sizes must be used
suppid, stkid                 number(2)
suppname, stkname             varchar2(30)
sellprice, purchaseprice      number(6,2)
```

MY response to this was:

```
CREATE Table SUPPLIER(
suppid Number(2) NOT NULL,
suppname varchar2(30),
stkid Number(2) NOT NULL,
citycode Number(2) NOT NULL,
Primary Key (suppid),
Foreign Key (citycode) references CITY
)

CREATE Table STOCKITEM( 
stkid Number(2) NOT NULL, 
stkname varchar2(30) , 
sellprice Number(6,2) , 
purchaseprice Number(6,2) , 
suppid Number(2) , 
Primary Key (stkid) , 
whid Number(2) NOT NULL, 
suppid Number(2) Foreign Key references SUPPLIER , 
whid Number(4) Foreign Key references WAREHOUSE 
)
```

Before you say that I am pointing to tables that I haven't created (and mark my Question down), Please note that the `WAREHOUSE` and `CITY` tables have been created in the Database that I am using already.

This code works and creates the tables. However, I received 0 marks out of 10 with no explanation. The above code is slightly improved from initially as (I believe) I have fixed up the NOT NULL attributes.

`Do my NOT NULL and FOREIGN KEY Constraints seem to have the right syntax?`

The ERD can be found in a pdf at https://www.dropbox.com/sh/eohlj5h073kwp4u/Ot08kbdY7Q

Before voting this question down please consult me first and I can adjust it. I am new to this website so give me a chance please

Comment: Why is this tagged for both MySQL and Oracle?  Which database are you using?

Comment: The `Number()` types imply Oracle... Please remove the MySQL tag if that's correct...

Comment: Sorry, I meant SQL. Is that better?

Comment: @DannyMahoney Yeah, and don't sweat people nagging, it's normal for us to get frustrated at little things when 100's of the same issues pop up in questions *every* day

Comment: I know, I have actually spent quite some time researching this and I was told that this was where to go if you are really stuck on something and there is a lot writing on me getting my head around SQL in the next 5 days, My Bachelor's Degree to be precise. I can code JavaScript, PHP, HTML etc. but for some reason SQL throws me and people just act like dicks about it. Starting to doubt the usefulness of this site

Comment: @DannyMahoney So what is the problem you're having ... other than a 0/10

Comment: That is why people are frustrated I think, and I don't blame them. I get no errors and the Database behaves normally as I add things and adjust etc. later on, I was just trying to figure out if I am missing some conventional Syntax, but people obviously just look at the title and start whinging that my code is shit (My last post. If the code was perfect I wouldn't need to be asking any questions?

Comment: "0 marks out of 10 with no explanation"  This is not a programming question.  This is a "how to I speak to my tutor" question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your foreign key syntax is *incorrect*.

Try this:

```
CONSTRAINT fk1 FOREIGN KEY (suppid)
    REFERENCES STOCKITEM(suppid)
```

Change your syntax to resemble the above.

Also, your primary key should be declared before any of your variables.

Lastly, the Primary key syntax in oracle looks like this:

```
CONSTRAINT pk PRIMARY KEY (suppid));
```

## Complete Code:

```
CREATE Table SUPPLIER(
suppid Number(2) NOT NULL,
suppname varchar2(30),
stkid Number(2) NOT NULL,
citycode Number(2) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pk1 PRIMARY KEY (suppid),
CONSTRAINT fk1 FOREIGN KEY (citycode) References ParentTable(primary_key_column)
)

CREATE Table STOCKITEM( 
stkid Number(2) NOT NULL, 
stkname varchar2(30) , 
sellprice Number(6,2) , 
purchaseprice Number(6,2) , 
suppid Number(2) , 
whid Number(2) NOT NULL, 
CONSTRAINT pk2 PRIMARY KEY (stkid),
CONSTRAINT fk2 FOREIGN KEY (suppid) References SUPPLIER(primary_key_column),
CONSTRAINT fk3 FOREIGN KEY (whid) References WAREHOUSE (primary_key_column)
)
```

## Note:

You will, of course, need to change *primary_key_column* in the above example to your column name.

Comment: would they all be fk1 or would it be fk1, fk2... etc. ?

Comment: @DannyMahoney see my latest update. In short, you should make them unique names.

Comment: @DannyMahoney Read: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/primary_keys.php

AND:

http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/foreign_keys/foreign_keys.php

Comment: Constraint names must be unique.  In my opinion, they should also be somewhat meaningful, at least to the extent that they should include the table name.

Comment: Now that you marked this as the answer, I'm curious about your comment about your code running without error.

Comment: @DanBracuk Danny, he is absolutely correct. Good, clean code uses *meaningful* names wherever possible.

Comment: That was the earlier version of the code which, according to previous cementers, was improved by my adjustments of the NOT NULL and Foreign Key. I must have sone something wrong in the process

Comment: @Evan those links are great! thanks everybody for helping me understand instead of just trolling

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
Foreign Key (citycode) references CITY
```

because it doesn't reference a field in that table.

Also, these appear to be in the wrong order:

```
Primary Key (stkid) , 
whid Number(2) NOT NULL,
```

I always declare all my fields before my keys.